# PuTTY run sh can't install fileinfo extension

Tags: shell, ssh, command, putty, fileinfo

I have a [DreamHost](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DreamHost) server, and I would like to install the fileinfo extension.

I managed to create a custom `php.ini` file that's cool, but I'm totally stuck at this part in [their documentation](http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Fileinfo):

> Please make sure to run 'dos2unix fileinfo_ext.sh' from the shell if you use a Windows-based editor to create this file.

So I am on Windows and running PuTTY and I have no clue about this part.

I copied `fileinfo_ext.sh` to my `cgi-bin` directory where my custom `php.ini` file is, but how do I go further? I'm totally lost how to run this command.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"dos2unix" is a utility used to convert file from Windows line endings (CR+LF) to Unix line endings (LF).

So if you use [Notepad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad_%28software%29) to edit the file it will have Windows line endings. So dos2unix should be used on your computer (for that file) before sending it by FTP (or executing it on the host if you have ssh access and they have dos2unix).

But if you already use an editor which supports converting to Unix line endings, like [UltraEdit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UltraEdit) or [Notepad++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad_%28software%29) then all you need is to do a "convert to Unix" before saving the file.

Comment: m if its not a big request, and sorry, can you post a tutorial for this if its not a big request, im totally a beginner noob with ssh

Comment: i found out how to run the command im getting premisson denied error, can you give me a hint about this

Comment: I really recommend using a better file editor for windows like [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) and then when you have your file open in it.. just go in the Edit -> EOL Conversion -> Unix  then your file will be in unix format.. then just upload it and it should work!

Answer (score 0):

You run the command as explained in the message. SSH to the server and login. Then `cd` to the location of the file, something like `cd /path/to/your/site/cgi-bin` and then run `dos2unix fileinfo_ext.sh`.

I hope this helps.